# PHP Random Array with no duplicates

Tags: php

I'm trying to get something right when I reload the browser the array changes randomly with no duplicate. When I reload the browser I saw duplicate array coming randomly, please help me.

Here is the code

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php


        $size = 3; $strl = "what"; $fitness1 = array("steps $strl", "dizziness $strl", "$strl symptoms  ", "treatment $strl", "obesity $strl","$strl discharge");

        $fitness1 = array_unique($fitness1);

        $number = 1;

        for ($b = 0; $b < $size ;$b++){


           echo $number++ . "<table><tr><td> " . $fitness1[array_rand($fitness1)] . "<td></tr></table>";echo $number++ . "<table><tr><td> " . $fitness1[array_rand($fitness1)] . "<td></tr></table>";




    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){



        }
    } 

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at `shuffle()`

Comment: So table needs to have unique values? Also, please indent your code

Comment: Thanks, I have tried, all could but not working!

Comment: When you reload the browser, there's nothing keeping track of anything from previous requests. You'll need to maintain that somehow, probably using session. Here's an example of something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458831/casting-php-into-an-array-and-looping-through

Comment: Thanks, I tried it still duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$number = 1;
do {
    shuffle($fitness1);
    echo "<tr><td>" . ($number++) ."</td><td>" . array_shift($fitness1) ."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . ($number++) ."</td><td>" . array_shift($fitness1) ."</td></tr>";
    $i++;
} while ($i < $size && !empty($fitness1));
```

> `shuffle()` This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array
>   Blockquote

*So each time you reload the page, the order will be different*

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

> `array_shift()` shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

*Once the value is printed, it will be removed from the array. So no repeated values*

Comment: Thanks, it works well, I really appreciate, you save my time.